# Is a gensim vocab index the index in the corresponding 1-hot-vector?

Tags: gensim, word2vec, one-hot-encoding

I am doing research that requires direct manipulation & embedding of one-hot vectors and I am trying to use gensim to load a pretrained word2vec model for this.

The problem is they don't seem to have a direct api for working with 1-hot-vectors. And I am looking for work arounds.

So I wanted to know if anyone knows of a way to do this? Or more specifically if these vocab indices (which are defined quite ambiguously). Could be indices into corresponding 1-hot-vectors?

Context I have found:

- Seems [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40458742/gensim-word2vec-accessing-in-out-vectors) is related but I tried accessing the 'input embeddings' (assuming they were one-hot representations), via model.syn0 (from link in answer), but I got a non-sparse matrix...
- Also appears [they refer to word indices as 'doctags'](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html) (search for Doctag/index).
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47117569/how-to-get-word2index-from-gensim) is another question giving some context to the indices (although not quite answering my question).
- [Here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html) is the official documentation:

################################################

class gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab(**kwargs)
Bases: object

A single vocabulary item, used internally for collecting per-word frequency/sampling info, and for constructing binary trees (incl. both word leaves and inner nodes).

################################################

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can think of the `index` (position) of gensim's `Word2Vec` word-vectors as being the one dimension that would be `1.0` – with all other V dimensions, where V is the count of unique words, being `0.0`.

The implementation doesn't actually ever create one-hot vectors, as a sparse or explicit representation. It's just using the word's index as a look-up for its dense vector – following in the path of the `word2vec.c` code from Google on which the gensim implementation was originally based.

(The term 'doctags' is only relevant in the `Doc2Vec` – aka 'Paragraph Vector' – implementation. There it is the name for the distinct tokens/ints that are used for looking up document-vectors, using a different namespace from in-document words. That is, in `Doc2Vec` you could use `'doc_007'` as a doc-vector name, aka a 'doctag', and even if the string-token `'doc_007'` also appears as a word inside documents, the doc-vector referenced by doctag-key `'doc_007'` and the word-vector referenced by word-key `'doc_007'` wouldn't be the same internal vector.)